# java .lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type

Tags: debugging, jsp, exception, web-applications, jakarta-ee

How do you make sense of exceptions like this? It doesn't add up because the CatalogFacade does compile fine, and  By the way, I do implement the classes they ask for. "Any of" seems like it's not needed to have all of them.

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:        ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
```

Which is Inside this surrounding error message, that seems a bit vague:

```
     [exec] remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while lo
ading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java
.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC1430: Unable to add listener of type: com.sun
.javaee.blueprints.petstore.model.CatalogFacade, because it does not implement a
ny of the required ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, Serv
letRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or Htt
pSessionAttributeListener interfaces. Please see server.log for more details.
     [exec] Command deploy failed.
```

BUILD FAILED
C:\LatestPS\trunk\ws\bp-project\app-server-ant.xml:379: exec returned: 1

I've been trying things all night . It's not clear.
By the way, to the best of my knowledge..there's nothing significant at app-server-ant.xml:379..

Here's the Full log(I know it's quite big):
[image]

Some more of files are here : http://www.adelazzam.com/so.html

Comment: Looks like a bad config in your server.xml, context.xml or web.xml. Have you made changes to either?

Comment: yes, there is a web.xml file. There are various other files too, like app-server-ant.xml - could this be it?

Comment: So it might be an error in something like this: `<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/PetstoreDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>`    ?

Comment: Could you update your post with the entirety of the exception logged (full message and stacktrace) and the contents of your web.xml, context.xml and (if you've modified it) your server.xml.

Comment: Thank You So Much - yes I updated it with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there in the error-message. The `<listener>` you specify in your web.xml, `CatalogFacade` does not implement the required Listener interface, specified by the servlet specification.

Check the implementation of your `CatalogFacade`. Depending on what type of listener it should be (that is, what lifecycle events should it be notified of) it must implement one of ServletContextListener, ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletRequestListener, ServletRequestAttributeListener, HttpSessionListener, or HttpSessionAttributeListener.

Comment: I think I am seeing this clearer now. I've ruled out the HttpSessionListener or HttpSessionAttributeListener interfaces, for example.  I'm thinking it might be an issue between Java 1.5 and 1.6 , differences in ServletContextListener etc? The relevant code in the class is small - two functions.  Thank You Very Much and Good Morning to you!

Comment: Yes, that could be an issue. If you ARE implementing one of the required interfaces, make sure you are compiling with the same level of Java as you are running your server on and the correct servlet-api version (2.5, it looks like from your web.xml) jar files. Another "common" mistake is to include the servlet-api jar in your WEB-INF/lib, which can lead to inconsistencies and class collisions as the servlet api is already present in Tomcat.

Comment: That's very helpful information and I'm on it!  So by "servlet-api version " this is GlassFish here(which comes with Tomcat I think)? I shal lcheck the WEB-INF/lib folder. Thank You So Much

Comment: Wow ! It's working now Yay :) When I switched back to Java EE 5 (glassfish 2.1), and fixed a passwd issue, it loaded up. Here's a pic too! Thank You So Much, I owe you!

Comment: Nice :) Good luck going forward!